# Task has long Schedule Delay on Spark UI and it failed because of GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark application which load 1 million rows of data from a database into 201 partitions and then write as parquet files. The application code may look like:

```
dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(...).load()
dataframe_over_range = dataframe.filter("date >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'")
if dataframe_over_range.head(1):
    for date in dates: # dates was a list of date
        dataframe_daily = dataframe_over_range.filter(f"date >= '{date} 00:00:00'").filter(f"date <= '{date} 23:59:59'")
        dataframe_daily.write.parquet('s3://...', mode='overwrite')
```

But Spark always ends up with 200 task SUCCESS and 1 task FAILED:

[image: 1 failed]

The failed task got an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in executor, and it had a long Scheduler Delay in Spark UI:

[image: long delay]

What may be the reason of this problem ?

==========Update==========

As @walking said, I change my code to this format:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(...).load()
dataframe_over_range = dataframe.filter("date >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'")
if dataframe_over_range.head(1):
    datafram_over_range.withColumn('partition_date', date_format(tb_config['date_col'], 'yyyy-MM-dd')).write.partitionBy('partition_date').parquet('s3://...')
```

But the problem was still the same, there's one task failed with long Scheduler Delay. But what makes me curious is that I found all parquet files were actually written to file system. What does Spark do after finish writing ?

==========Update 2==========

I've check the GC log of Spark, and I found the number of `FinalReference` and `WeakReference` grows after the failed task start, and also number of `promoted` grows too. This would lead to Full GC after few minutes, and finally too many Full GC leads to `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: not sure about the error but looping over dates and performing X write is very unsparky.
you should run: dataframe_over_range.filter(col("date").isin(dates)).write.partitionBy('date').parquet(...) for one operation.

also can you check your DB query history? I think you are running the same query 200+ times.

Comment: Hi @walking thanks for your suggestion, I've try your way but the problem was still the same, I've updated the question. What made me curious was that I found all parquet files were actually written successfully. Do you have idea what's that last task doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. I'm using the jdbc options `lowerBound` and `upperBound` in a wrong way. This two options are only for data partition but not for filtering data from database, you should filter data via using subquery in `dbtable` option or `query` option.

For example, I want to load data which id between `0` and `1000000`, and seperate into 10 partitions, the wrong way is:

```
spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
  ...,
  dbtable='my_table',
  partitionColumn='id',
  lowerBound=0,
  upperBound=1000000,
  numPartitions=10
  ...
).load()
```

This would cause the query of the last partition be like `select * from my_table where id >= 900000` which doesn't have upper bound. The right way should be:

```
spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
  ...,
  dbtable='(select * from my_table where id between 0 and 1000000) t',
  partitionColumn='id',
  lowerBound=0,
  upperBound=1000000,
  numPartitions=10
  ...
).load()
```